# Connect Local SQL Database to Budibase

Tags: sql-server, ssms, budibase

I have a SQL Server database on my machine that I use with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (using Windows auth). I want to connect this database to BudiBase. It asks for Host, Port, User, and Password.

Where do I find these details?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Host name:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Port (generally 1433):

```
USE MASTER
GO
XP_READERRORLOG 0, 1, N'SERVER IS LISTENING ON' 
GO
```

If you are only using Windows authentication, you need to create new credentials in security -> logins.